# What is the cardinality of $^*\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals, filters

A friend of mine was trying to find a field with cardinality bigger than $\aleph_1$. Then I come up with a method that constructs the real number system by using arithmetical ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$, and we get $^*\mathbb{N}$, $^*\mathbb{Z}$, and $^*\mathbb{Q}$, where $^*\mathbb{Q}$ is a field. Then we pick elements in $^*\mathbb{Q}$ that follows Archimedes property to form $\mathbb{Q}_<$, and an equivalence relation $\sim $ on $\mathbb{Q}_<$ to form $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Q}_</\sim$.

It has been proved that the space of all ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$ is a huge space, with cardinality $2^{2^\omega}$. Then what is the cardinality of $^*\mathbb{Q}$? Also, does $|^*\mathbb{N}| = |^*\mathbb{Z}| = |^*\mathbb{Q}|$? If not, what are cardinalities of them?

Comment: Yes $|^*\mathbb{N}| = |^*\mathbb{Z}| = |^*\mathbb{Q}|$.  What happens when you try to prove it?  Perhaps adapt the usual proofs that $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{Z}| = |\mathbb{Q}|$.

Comment: "the space of all ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$ is a huge space".   This is irrelevant to your question, since we use only **one** ultrafilter to construct $^*\mathbb{N}$, $^*\mathbb{Q}$, $^*\mathbb{R}$, etc.

Comment: Also, the cardinality of ${^*}\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathfrak{c}$, the cardinality of the set of real numbers. It follows from for each real number $r$ we can choose a hyperrational $q\in{^*}\mathbb{Q}$ that is infinitely close to $r$, so $\mathfrak{c}\le|{^*}\mathbb{Q}|$. For an upper bound, remind that there is a surjection from the function set $\mathbb{Q^N}$ to ${^*}\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: (Regarding your friend's question, consider the field of rationals with uncountably many variables. Or you may apply the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem or an ultrapower construction with an ultrafilter over a large set.)

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not very sure about the cardinality of $^*\mathbb{Q}$, I can tell you that $|^*\mathbb{Q}|=|^*\mathbb{Z}|=|^*\mathbb{N}|$ mainly because $|\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{N}|$, and hence their extensions will also have a similar cardinality.